# Shared Services in Angular 6 outside of Core module

Tags: angular

Best practices in Angular 6 dictate the creation of a `Core module` (imported in the `Root` module) which, apart from anything else, will accommodate all the services which will be shared across the application. The above does include lazy loaded modules which will have access to those services.
However, is it still necessary to place the shared services inside this Core module since now services are being directly registered in the root Injector node via

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
```

and in fact they are decoupled from any module?

Comment: Looks like this is all documented here: https://angular.io/guide/providers

Comment: Are you sure about that? There is nothing written about Core module...

Comment: That’s because a Core module isn’t required to run an application. Adding a Core module is a design decision by the developer. The Root, or App, module is always there, along with the root DI container. The idea of a [Core](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#core-feature-module) module is style guide *suggestion*.

Answer (score -1):

With Angular 6 there is **definitely no need** to place Shared Services in Core module. The key point is services with `providedIn`, bypass modules and become autonomous. They are registered automatically to the `root Injector node` and become available to the whole application. So, we don't have to worry even about lazy loaded modules which can access those services.

However, the above does not mean we have to get rid of `Core module` since there are other functionalities which are being implemented through it.

Comment: You figured out the solution to your own question and wrote the answer in just 2min? We are hiring, btw ;-)

Comment: Very smart comment!! I just wanted to share something with the community...

Comment: ...and I appreciate that. I think this can be helpful especially for people migrating from older Angular versions